# How to get twitter profile information with meteors accounts-twitter?

Tags: meteor, twitter, meteor-accounts

I built a twitter login in my `meteor` app by using the `accounts-twitter` package according to the [official meteor docs](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#supported-login-services).

However when I try to get the user's Twitter account information by querying:

```
Meteor.users.find().fetch();
```

I only get a `profile` object with the twitter screen name but no other data in it. How can I get the other data, like profile picture, etc. ?

I was expecting a `service` object containing this information as stated in [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/meteor/tutorial/add-twitter-login-system-meteor-application).

I'm using Meteor 1.6 with accounts-twitter@1.4.1

Comment: The accounts twitter is only providing login functionality using `oauth` and thus only stores the login token. It is not designed to consume the twitter API.

Comment: Really? There are multiple tutorials (including the one above) with descriptions how to access twitter profile information. I even get the twitter screen name.

Comment: Oh ok I see. What does your mongo console return when you enter `db.users.find().pretty()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this query on the client side, please be sure that you are actually publishing not only the "profile" field, but also the "services" field.
In your publish function make sure you return a cursor like this return `Meteor.publish("allUsers", function() { return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields : { profile : 1, services : 1 } }) })` this will publish all users with their profile and service fields only (+ _id which gets included always). Then make sure to subscribe to that publish on your page in order to get that data (this usually happens in the controller for the page) `Meteor.subsribe("allUsers")`. Then you should be able to see the service fields as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! By the way, the property is named `services` with a tailing s.

Comment: @AdrianKrebs no problem, glad it worked out. Yep, typo on my end, fixed it for future reference, thanks.